# webclient.downloadfile is deleting existing file

Tags: c#

This specific line of code:
`webClient.DownloadFile(uri, FilePath);`
is deleting existing file in case if webClient.DownloadFile hits with 502 error, is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

I wanted to retain old file incase of download failure

And there is no documentation available for this behavior.

Comment: Download it to a temporary file initially. Then, when downloaded successfully, copy the temporary file over the original file.

Comment: You can add in any case a timestamp to the filesname, that would solve your problem as well. After that, you can rename the newest timestamp to the needed name and delete the older files if they are not needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code, WebClient initializes a `FileStream` with `FileMode.Create` and `FileAccess.Write`, and writes the response into that. If an error occurs obtaining the response, a flag will be set and the file will be deleted.

To circumvent the inadvertent deletion of files, first download into a new, temporary file and move that file over the existing one if the operation succeeds.

Comment: I wish they could open file handle after successful download. Thanks for tip, i'm thinking same but just wanted to check if there is a flag i can set to avoid this.

Comment: The WebClient code doesn't allow to modify this behavior, it's hardcoded. You _could_ inherit from HttpWebRequest and make that new class not throw exceptions, then feed that derived type to the WebClient in an overridden GetWebRequest(), so it doesn't end up in the catch clause which deletes the file. But that might cause other exceptions internally in the WebClient when an HTTP error occurs.

Comment: @CodeCaster that will not help, because as soon as you do `new FileStream(FileMode.Create, ...)` - its contents are lost (file becomes empty).

Comment: @Evk heh, I typed that in my answer and forgot that while commenting. Yes, the file will remain in that case, but it'll be empty. So no, there's no solution other than to download into a temporary file.